# How to use /give command to give enchanted items in Minecraft Bedrock (PS4)?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to `/give` a player an enchanted sword using commands, but it isn't working. This is the command:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{Id:16,lvl:1}]}
```

No matter what I try, it insists that there is a missing “}” or object member name.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

the command i would use would just to type /give @s diamond_sword if it doesn't work for you, then im sorry, thats all the advice i have. And if you want it enchanted, after youve got the sword, you use the command /enchant.